# Изменить прозрачность элементов при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, нужно чтобы при прокрутке к div только этот div менял прозрачность.
При скррол вниз плавно затухал, при скролле вверх появлялся.
Помогите отредактировать этот код. Или дайте пример как это реализовать.
Заранее спасибо!

Добавлю несколько примеров.
Но там только один блок, а как сделать несколько?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mtp7tcg/)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/michaeldoyle/pen/Bhsif)

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
     $('div').css({
        opacity: function() {
             var elementHeight = $(this).height();
           return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
         }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="background: silver">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
</div>
<div style="background: grey">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
</div>
<div style="background: #2b2a2a">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно какой `div` должен затухать?

Comment: @entithat каждый , есть три DIV, когда мы начинаем скроллить страницу, первый должен затухать, потом когда дойдем к второму DIV, второй должен затухать и тд, а при скролле вверх, должны появляться так само по очереди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришла в голову такая идея.

*Уже скорость и плавность появления/исчезновения можно поменять.* 
Коротко говоря, в коде я проверяю видно ли блок, если да, то меняем прозрачность.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('div').each(function(i, el) { // Для каждого блока
    var pTop = $(el).offset().top; // Позиция блока относительно топа
    var height = $(el).height(); // Высота блока

    var top = pTop - sTop + height; // Находим позицию блока относительно начала окна
    if (top > 0) { // Если блок видно, то меняем прозрачность
      $(el).css({
        opacity: function() {
          var elementHeight = $(el).height();
          return 1 - top / 100 + height / 100;
        }
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 300%;
  padding-top: 150px; /* Для наглядности */
}

div {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="background: silver;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
  </div>

  <div style="background: gray">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
  </div>

  <div style="background: #2b2a2a">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </p>
  </div>
</body>
```